# Is there any way to setup a common code block (i.e. 'before each') for examples that use receive matchers in RSpec?

Tags: rspec

Here's an example of a use-case where we're testing to ensure that `DinnerTable#arrange` calls another method `DinnerTable#moar_chairs` only if arranging for guests

```
describe DinnerTable do
  subject(:table) { DinnerTable.new }

  describe "#arrange" do
    context "when arranging for family" do
      let(:group) { :family }
      it "doesn't get extra chairs" do
        expect(table).not_to receive(:moar_chairs)
        table.arrange(group)
      end
    end

    context "when arranging for guests" do
      let(:group) { :guests }
      it "gets extra chairs" do
        expect(table).to receive(:moar_chairs)
        table.arrange(group)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Notice how the context sets up the group to be arranged for (family or guests), but then we still just call the relevant method, `arrange`, independently in every single example (making the context somewhat pointless).

Normally putting that method in a `before` block would work because most matchers expect a current, testable condition, but since we're using the `receive` matcher, which expects something to happen in the future, we can't do that, or the test will fail.  Putting it in an `after` block also fails, since the expectation returns false before executing the `after` block.  If only we had some sort of `during` block that would run just before the end of the example...

```
describe DinnerTable do
  subject(:table) { DinnerTable.new }

  describe "#arrange" do
    during { table.arrange(group) }

    context "when arranging for family" do
      let(:group) { :family }
      it { should_not receive(:moar_chairs) }
    end

    context "when arranging for guests" do
      let(:group) { :guests }
      it { should receive(:moar_chairs) }
    end
  end
end
```

(Or perhaps it could be called `action` or `predicate` to go along with `subject`?  Another option would be to run the after block before letting the receive matcher fail... but I don't know what kind of other consequences that would have.

Are there any other good patterns for setting up a common block for multiple examples with `receive` matchers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oooh, I was wrong!  I must have been doing something wrong the first time, because putting the method in an `after` block *does* work :D  Yay!

So:

```
describe DinnerTable do
  subject(:table) { DinnerTable.new }

  describe "#arrange" do
    after { table.arrange(group) }

    context "when arranging for family" do
      let(:group) { :family }
      it { should_not receive(:moar_chairs) }
    end

    context "when arranging for guests" do
      let(:group) { :guests }
      it { should receive(:moar_chairs) }
    end
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**

Or alternately, for better semantics, add a spec helper method called action that looks like this:

```
def action(&block)
  shared_context "run action before", run_action: :first do
    before(&block)
  end
  shared_context "run action after", run_action: :last do
    after(&block)
  end
end
```

and then the examples would look like:

```
describe DinnerTable do
  subject(:table) { DinnerTable.new }

  describe "#arrange", run_action: :last do
    action { table.arrange(group) }

    context "when arranging for family" do
      let(:group) { :family }
      specify { table.should_not receive(:moar_chairs) }
    end

    context "when arranging for guests" do
      let(:group) { :guests }
      specify { table.should receive(:moar_chairs) }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Something about this rubs me the wrong way. Your initial version was a bit longer and more repetitive, but the intent was easier to discern.

Comment: Yeah... there is that.  But I feel like for describe blocks that describe a simple method, there should be a way to define the method you're describing once, and then have several examples that make various assertions about the workings of that method - the same way you can setup the `subject` once and use it in all the examples.  It could be the `predicate`.  But maybe Peter's way of defining the `predicate` is more maintainable / reusable, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The `receive` expectations need to be set prior to executing the code under test. The following will work and eliminate some duplication (`DinnerTable` class definition provided for illustration purposes only):

```
class DinnerTable

  def arrange(group)
    moar_chairs if group == :guests 
  end

  def moar_chairs
  end

end

describe DinnerTable do
  let(:table) { DinnerTable.new }
  let(:arrange) { table.arrange(group) }

  describe "#arrange" do
    context "when arranging for family" do
      let(:group) { :family }
      it "doesn't get extra chairs" do
        expect(table).not_to receive(:moar_chairs)
        arrange
      end
    end

    context "when arranging for guests" do
      let(:group) { :guests }
      it "gets extra chairs" do
        expect(table).to receive(:moar_chairs)
        arrange
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Oops - sorry, the fact that I called arrange before the receive matcher was a typo - fixed! :)  But yeah, this is marginally better than the (now fixed) original pattern... it just seems like the calling of arrange should be something that can be setup as context for the describe block, and the only reason it's not possible is because we happen to be using the receive matcher...